# Architecture problems, what is armhf

Tags: system-installation

By failing to install some i386 architecture packages, i assumed i was running on amd64 architecture but when i input

```
sudo dpkg --print-architecture
```

the output is `armhf`.
Can someone explain what it means? I was expecting amd64 as an output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`armhf` is an architecture used mostly in mobile devices and netbooks. Its more common name is ARM, or the Acorn RISC (reduced instruction set computing) Machine (see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) for more information). Some packages that are not multi-arch will not install properly, whether they are `i386` or not.

Side note: `amd64` architecture can most of the time install and run `i386` architecture programs.

Comment: So can i run run amd64 architecture packages with armhf?

Comment: No. armhf is the least powerful of the three. The other two may be able to run armhf packages, but I haven't tested that.

Comment: So all my attempt to install steam, wine skype etc are in vaine?

Comment: Sorry to say it, but yes. There may be packages on the Internet that people have adapted for ARM systems, though. It's worth a Google search  (for Skype, download the file from their website if you haven't tried already).

Comment: I just found this topic https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=17701 how is it possible considering what you told me earlier?

Comment: @Cyril: They are running wine in qemu, a windows emulator (wine) in x86 emulator (qemu) on ARM ... forget about it - it works, but sloooooooowly.

Comment: What does `hf` stand for?

Comment: @CiroSantilli巴拿馬文件六四事件法轮功 Sorry for the late reply. From [this forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=11177&p=123525), it stands for "hard-float" which has to do with the way calculations are performed. Software developed for the `armhf` architecture take advantage of the processor's ability to calculate floating-point computations and sends the instructions directly to the processor instead of using software libraries. This results in a much quicker computation time.